# How does Prolog answer this query?

Tags: prolog, backtracking, unification

```
likes(alice, sports).
likes(alice, music).
likes(carol, music).
likes(david,animals).
likes(david,X) :- likes(X,sports).
likes(alice,X) :- likes(david,X).

?- likes(alice,X).
```

I've been trying to learn prolog an few days now, and when I attempted this question, I realised that I don't completely understand when the variables are instantiated and used. The initial goal is : `likes(alice , X)`. After that, the next goal to prove is `likes(david , X)`? Then is it `likes(X, sports)`. Then does `X` become `alice`?

**Another route:**

The initial goal is : `likes(alice , X)`. After that, the next goal to prove is `likes(david , X)`? Then `X` becomes `sports`. Then the goal becomes `likes(david , sports)`. Then I don't know.

Could someone please indicate where my thinking is flawed.

Comment: Variables are never "instantiated" - they are **unified**.

Comment: The *goal* doesn't become `likes(david, sports)`. The *goal* in the predicate body for `likes(alice, X)` is `likes(david, X)` which is made true when `X` is unified with `sports`, so `X = sports` is the (or at least "a") solution to the query, `likes(david, X)`. Since that's the end of the predicate clause for `likes(alice, X)`, then that means `likes(alice, X)` succeeds with `X = sports`.

Comment: @lurker - I'm not sure if that makes it clearer. The variable is already in existence before it is unified - prior to unification it is a free variable, but afterwards it simply is the same as an existing atom or variable. Nothing is actually instantiated at the time of unification. If a variable is unified with an atom then the variable effectively becomes a reference to the atom - nothing was instantiated. If a variable is unified with another (free) variable this becomes even more complicated as you couldn't say anything at all was instantiated then.

Comment: @lurker - Please never remove comments like that. It makes understanding the flow of the comments very difficult. Only delete if it doesn't affect the context.

Comment: @Enigmativity if I have the expression, `X = a, foo(X).` then, in the context of the call to `foo`, isn't `X` referred to as being *instantiated*?

Comment: @lurker - the `X` is already unified with `a` before the call to `foo(X)` takes place. It's effectively `foo(a)` at that point in time.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, I understand that. But that doesn't really answer my question. The expression, as written, is still `foo(X)` (although `foo/1` will be executed with `a` as the argument since `X` was previously unified with `a`).

Comment: @lurker - Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking. Yes, it can be referred to as instantiated (but I prefer not to think of it like that to avoid the confusion with the term from imperative programming). Prolog works a bit like a time machine, in my view, so if I have `X = Y, Y = Z, Z = a` then it kind of goes back in time to instantiate `X` with `a` (and `Y` too), but it is also ephemeral in nature that as soon as backtracking occurs the unifications can be undone. It just seems odd to me that things can be "uninstantiated".

Comment: @Enigmativity I think I understand the technical reasons for your objections to the terminology, especially with regard to imperative programming implications. The terminology, albeit imperfect, is commonly used (*e.g.*, a Prolog built-in call can throw an *instantiation* error).

Comment: @lurker - It's a technical issue, but also a more abstract one. Since Prolog is an implementation of Horn Calculus it really should be viewed as an instantaneous calculation - like the solutions of a quadratic equation; they exist the instant you write down the problem regardless of when you actually work them out. If you view Prolog in this way I think it help to understand the language at its core. And once you do then you can start applying the practical considerations of the interpreter. Otherwise it's just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code Prolog would try to unify the goal against he first fact, `likes(alice, sports).`, and it would succeed. `X` would be unified with `sports`.

If you asked Prolog to continue then it would next unify `X` with `music` (the second fact).

And if you continued again it would skip the next three facts/rules, and try to prove `likes(alice,X) :- likes(david,X).`. This would lead to trying to prove `likes(david,X)` which succeeds with the fact `likes(david,animals)` so `X`, in the original goal, would unify with `animals`.

And if you asked it to continue again you would find that it tries to prove `likes(david,X) :- likes(X,sports).` which leads to `X` unifying with `alice`, so the original goal would suggest that `alice` `likes` `alice`.

When I ran your code with this goal:

```
?- likes(alice,X), write(X), nl, fail.
```

...I got this output:

```
sports
music
animals
alice
No.
```

With the final `No.` being caused because I had the `fail` predicate in my goal. It was a goal that was always going to fail, but it produced a side-effect by outputting the intermediate result of `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the code. First, you have some facts:

```
likes(alice, sports).    % Alice likes sports
likes(alice, music).     % Alice likes music
likes(carol, music).     % Carol likes music
likes(david, animals).   % David likes animals
```

Just given these facts, you can make basic queries:

```
?- likes(alice, sports).   % Does Alice like sports?
true ;
false.  % no more solutions
```

So, yes, Alice likes sports (the result was `true`). Does Alice like animals?

```
?- likes(alice, animals).
false.
```

Evidently not. At least, according to the data we have, we cannot prove that Alice likes animals. (Remember, we only have the facts so far, but none of the rules, shown below.)

Well then, what does Alice like, according to the facts?

```
?- likes(alice, X).
X = sports ;
X = music.
```

Alice likes sports and music.

Now let's add in your rules:

```
likes(david, X) :- likes(X, sports).
```

This says that, *David likes someone (`X`) if that someone (`X`) likes sports*.

Let's see who/what David likes:

```
?- likes(david, X).
X = animals ;
X = alice ;
false  % no more solutions
```

So David likes animals (because a fact says so), and David likes Alice (because we have a rule that says David likes X if X likes sports, and Alice likes sports).

Your other rule:

```
likes(alice, X) :- likes(david, X).
```

Says, *Alice likes someone (`X`) if David likes that same someone (`X`)*.

With the new rules added, let's see who/what Alice likes:

```
?- likes(alice, X).
X = sports ;
X = music ;
X = animals ;
X = alice ;
false
```

Alice likes sports and music (because the facts say so). Alice likes animals because David likes animals and the rule says that if David likes X, then Alice likes X. Alice also evidently likes herself because, according to the first rule, we showed that David likes Alice. According to the second rule, Alice likes anyone that David likes. Therefore, Alice likes Alice.

You can get the step-by-step execution by running `trace.` then execute your query.

Note that this is fairly well behaved with these simple rules and facts. In more complex cases you have to be careful about naming your rules and your facts the same way because it can lead to infinite logical loops.